# PHP, PHP5 tags merge

Tags: discussion, tags

I know PHP5 is very different from previous versions and that all (its a new version!) but do we need a split between the tags [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php) and [php5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php5)?

Are not talking about the same thing in the end? Can you not figure out which version is refereed in a question just by reading it?

On the same note do we need a [python2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python2) and a [python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python3) separation in our tags?

I say php5 is still php and there is no need to be so specific on the tags.

Should [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php) and [php5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php5) be merged?

Answer (score 4):

Since php4 is no longer in the repos, and [php5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php5) is installed by default, there really is no need for a [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php) and [php5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php5) tag. [php5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php5) should be a synonym of [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php). However, since both [python2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python2) and [python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python3) exist in the repos, there should be separate tags as I've come to learn [python2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python2) and [python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python3) are *very* different.

Comment: Agree, but the point with the python tag was that they are so different yet there is only one necessary tag for the both versions, why 2 for php? I was not suggesting 2 python tags ;)

Comment: **We definitely need both a Python 2.x and Python 3.x tag.** They are very different and very rarely will a question not be specific to one or the other.